# Sound files path is giving error

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, c#-4.0, setup-deployment

i have made a windows form application in which i am using some sound files. i saved these file into new folder which i integrated in program files folder. now when i install it into my computer, it works fine. but in other computer, it is giving error. error is because of folder i integrated in setup is now in program files(x86) folder. so application can't find sound files. 
i Just want that when my setup installs, the folder must be copied into program files folder, Not in program files(x86) folder.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your software will be installed into Program File folder only if it's x64 version, otherwise it will be automatically installed in Program Files(x86).  The good practise is not to hard-code paths at all, just set the path to be `PathOfRunnedExe + \Sounds\` or something like that

Comment: isn't there any way to install it into program files folder??

Comment: Well basically you can if you use some third-party installation wizards. (p.s. Read my previous comment, I updated it)

Comment: The likely problem here is that you are installing a 64-bit program (Platform target = AnyCPU) with a 32-bit installer.  So it ends up in the wrong program files directory.  Changing the platform target setting to force it to always run in 32-bit mode is a simple workaround.  So is using the proper full path name for the files, it avoids outright failure on a machine where the program files directory is not named "Program Files", like it will be on any non-English version of Windows.

Comment: @Hoh Thank You very much i used AppDomain class and got path for executable file. it worked for me . Thanks again..

Comment: I just added my comments as answer, if that helped you feel free to mark it as answer and upvote it. I'm glad I helped you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your software will be installed into Program File folder only if it's x64 version, otherwise it will be automatically installed in Program Files(x86). The good practise is not to hard-code paths at all, just set the path to be `PathOfRunnedExe + \Sounds` or something like that.

You can if you use some third-party installation wizards to get a chance to change installation path for your software.